# Bigquery-GROUP BY doesn't do anything

Tags: google-bigquery

I wan't to catergorize a very large table from reddit comments. could you tell me why this doesn't work?

```
SELECT  link_id,  body ,
FROM
  [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_03]
group BY  1,  2
limit 1000
```

Comment: what's your goal? that query as is doesn't seem to bring any interesting result

Comment: Could you describe in more detail how exactly that query does not work for you?  Are there error messages, or...?

Comment: my goal is to create groups of messeges by Link_id.

Comment: no errors. but the messeges don't turn up sorted

Answer (score 0):

> no errors. but the messeges don't turn up **sorted**

Looks like you are getting GROUP BY too literally and expecting rows to be output for you visually groupped - that is not what GROUP BY does
It is for computing aggregations - check [GROUP BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#groupby) clause  for more details

In your case [ORDER BY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#orderby) looks more adecvate to your expectation

For example, below query returns 3 most lengthy comments for each link_id and output is groupped (in a sense of sorting - not aggregating)

```
SELECT 
  link_id,  body
FROM (
  SELECT  
    link_id, body, 
    LENGTH(body) AS len, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY link_id ORDER BY len DESC) AS pos
  FROM
    [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_03]
)
WHERE pos < 4
ORDER BY link_id, pos
LIMIT 1000
```